# Retrieving data from another column based on entries in another column within same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table.

```
+----+-----------+--------+----------+
| sku|  strength |  color | option_1 |
+----+-----------+--------+----------+
|  1 | 40 lb     | (NULL) | strength |
|  2 | 50 lb     | black  | color    |
|  3 | (NULL)    | black  | color    | 
|  4 | (NULL)    | red    | color    |
+----+-----------+--------+----------+
```

I want this table:

```
+----+-----------+--------+----------+----------------+
|sku | strength  | color  | option_1 | option_value_1 |
+----+-----------+--------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | 40 lb     | (NULL) | strength | 40 lb          |
|  2 | 50 lb     | black  | color    | black          |
|  3 | (NULL)    | black  | color    | black          |
|  4 | (NULL)    | red    | color    | red            |
+----+-----------+--------+----------+----------------+
```

I'm new to mysql. I'm trying to do this index-match or vlookup like query where option_1 determines which column to retrieve data from and send to option_value_1. I wasn't sure if I should do an inner join or a case clause since I have a much larger table with a lot more options than just color and strength.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple *searched case expression*, such as

```
case option_1
  when 'strength' then strength
  when 'color' then color
  when '...' then ...
else 'default option'
end as option_value_1
...
```

Comment: This was what I was initially going to do, but I want to see if there are any slicker solutions  maybe involving the sku to match.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a `JOIN` here. However, since you said there a lot more columns then it's going to be a long `CASE` expression to write. Also, if there's new column added then you need to remember to update the query from time to time. One way you can prevent that is using [Prepare statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html) :

1. Setting variables as `NULL` just in case

```
SET @sql := NULL;
SET @columns := NULL;
```

2. Constructing the `CASE` expression and assign to `@columns` variable:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('WHEN "',option_1,'" THEN ',option_1) SEPARATOR ' ') 
         INTO @columns
FROM mytable;
```

3. Constructing the final query by  appending the previously constructed `@columns` variable into the `@sql` variable:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT *, CASE option_1 ',@columns,' END AS option_value_1 FROM mytable;') 
        INTO @sql;
```

4. Prepare, execute and deallocate the final generated query in `@sql`:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

To check the variables you can run:

```
SELECT @columns;
SELECT @sql;
```

This will be good for you to test the query especially when the execution returned error; so that you can pin-point where the problem is and fix.

Note:
It's not necessary to have two variables in constructing the final query. I mean, you can just do a straight query construction to `@sql` by combining the `@columns` generating query with the `@sql` generating query. I personally separate them to make it easier to understand the components.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7b281c8c87f5a1fa8c98824b6e5d5a1)